# Separating data within a cell and duplicating row data

Tags: r

I have data that is within one cell, separated by spaces. 
For example, there is one column with city name such as "New York, NY" and then another column with the zip codes "12345 67891 23456".
What is a good method for separating this single row so that it could become three rows, with each having "New York, NY" and then having a single zip code associated?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(city = "New York, NY", zipcodes = "12345 67891 23456") %>%
  mutate(zipcodes = strsplit(zipcodes, "\\s+")) %>%
  unnest(zipcodes)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   city         zipcodes
#   <chr>        <chr>   
# 1 New York, NY 12345   
# 2 New York, NY 67891   
# 3 New York, NY 23456
```

Base R:

```r
dat <- data.frame(city = "New York, NY", zipcodes = "12345 67891 23456", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
zips <- strsplit(dat$zipcodes, "\\s+")
data.frame(city=rep(dat$city, each = lengths(zips)), zipcode = unlist(zips))
#           city zipcode
# 1 New York, NY   12345
# 2 New York, NY   67891
# 3 New York, NY   23456
```

One premise of this answer is that the zip codes are separated by one or more whitespace (space, tab, etc). If there are legitimate spaces (true in many countries), then @ThomasIsCoding's approach may be a better start in that it attempts to extract the specific elements. Both will fail where zip codes are alphanumeric and contain a space; for instance, the UK has `BS2 0JA` as a zip code. In that case, you'll need a lot more logic to extract them safely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `base R`, do you mean this kind of output?

```
s <- "New York, NY 12345 67891 23456"
data.frame(addr = paste0(gsub("(.*?\\s)\\d.*","\\1",s), unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\d+",s)))))
```

yielding

```
                addr
1 New York, NY 12345
2 New York, NY 67891
3 New York, NY 23456
```